# toast inside an asynctask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, toast

Please help how to work with this one. I'm doing a login and authenticate all the errors and possible exception. This is my code `

```
EditText un, pw;
ImageButton login;
TextView error;
ProgressDialog pd;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    un=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtUsername);
    pw=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtPassword);
    login=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    error=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.errTxt);


    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            new login().execute();


        }



    });


}
public class login extends AsyncTask{

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", un.getText().toString()));
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", pw.getText().toString()));
        //String valid = "1";
        String response = null;


        try {

            response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://www.cjcld.org/dvts1/mobile/login.php", postParameters);
            String res=response.toString();
           // res = res.trim();
            res= res.replaceAll("\\s+","");                              
            //error.setText(res);

           if(Integer.parseInt(res)>0){

            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", res));
             String result = null;
           try
           {
              result = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://www.cjcld.org/dvts1/mobile/status.php", postParameters);
              String res2=result.toString();
              res2= res2.replaceAll("\\s+","");    

              if(Integer.parseInt(res2)>0){

               Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), dashboard.class); 
               Bundle logval = new Bundle();

              logval.putString("uid", res);
              logval.putString("did", res2);
               myIntent.putExtras(logval);
               startActivity(myIntent);
              }else{

                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No Delivery", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              }
           }
           catch(Exception e)           
           {

               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }
           }
            else
            {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Sorry!! Incorrect Username or Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return null;
    }



}
```

When the toast is going to execute the program will close and prompt an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do it in the main Userinterface thread . like this

```
  MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"call your toast from the main ui thread",300).show();
                                    }
                                });
```

Comment: Sure! if this helped, you can mark my post as ans by ticking top left corner of my post :-)

Comment: @UsmanRiaz nice answer but inside that runonuithread how can we toast message custom...yeah and not with activity but with fragment..

Comment: Did you tried to toast like this. i think this would help no matter what is the container. and what do you mean by "toast message custom"

Answer (score 1):

`doInBackground` is a background non-UI thread and you **cannot do UI activities from there**.

On the other hand, the UI threads are onPreExecute, onProgressUpdate and onPostExecute. Your UI activity should happen only in one of these three functions.

You should try to **set a flag inside the doInBackground()** and then check the value of the flag in the `onPostExecute` and display the Toast message accordingly.

Comment: i try to do it but it seems that i have to minimize the used of http client it seems to be the error when i put it on that function.

Comment: I am sorry, but I really dont understand. Can you update your question with the new code you are trying right now ? Because I do not think there is any problem with the HttpClient.

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't post the error one cannot be sure, but as a rule of thumb **you should not modify UI from a background thread**. I would guess a toast qualify as UI modification?

Try launching the Toast (and the intent to your dashboard activity) from the `onPostExecute` or `onProgressUpdate` methods

Answer (score 0):

You cannot Toast from a background thread, which an Async Task's onBackground method is. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#doInBackground(Params...).

You could for instance override

```
protected void onPostExecute (Result result)
```

or

```
protected void onProgressUpdate (Progress... values)
```

and Toast from there as they are running on the UI thread.